Splitting a string on spaces but ignore section between double or single quotes
I need to split an input string at contiguous spaces into a list of strings. The input may include single or double quoted strings, which must be ignored.
How can I split a string at the spaces, but ignore quoted strings, so the result of splitting this
me   you   "us and them"   'everyone else' them

returns this?
me
you
us and them
everyone else
them

Duplicate of this question but for needing to ignore single-quoted strings, as well.

An alternative approach would be to match in order one or more of double-quoted strings, single-quoted strings, or non white spaces:
$people  = 'me   you   "us and them"   ''everyone else'' them'
$pattern = '(?:"(?:[^"])*"|''(?:[^''])*''|\S)+'
([regex]::Matches($people, $pattern)).Value

The order is important, you want the regex to match/grab the quoted items as a whole before trying to grab non white spaces.
The pattern:
(?:               #  Start a non-capturing group
   "(?:[^"])*"    #  match double-quoted string
   |              #  or
   '(?:[^'])*'    #  match single-quoted string
   |              #  or
   \S             #  match a non white space character
)+                #  repeat non-capturing group 1 or more times


This one is good but there's a problem. Two quoted strings without a space between them is returned as a single string: "us and them"'everyone else' is returned as is instead of "us and them" and 'everyone else'.

@sthames42, that is by design.  It is meant to be the equivalent to dividing a line on spaces, but not on spaces inside quoted sections.   For what you want, just remove the outer non capturing group and replace the \S with [^''\s"]+:  $pattern = '"(?:[^"])*"|''(?:[^''])*''|[^''\s"]+'

Did some performance testing and found virtually no difference between this solution and mine over 100,000 parsings of the same string. But I accepted this one because I prefer matching to splitting and I'm unclear on why the *$ qualifier is needed on mine. I know it doesn't work without it but I don't know why.

This excellent solution has been modified to ignore single-quoted strings, as well, and remove all leading and trailing quotes from each argument.
$people  = 'me   you   "us and them"   ''everyone else'' them'

$pattern = '(?x)
  [ ]+              # Split on one or more spaces (greedy)
  (?=               # if followed by one of the following:
    (?:[^"'']|      #   any character other a double or single quote, or 
    (?:"[^"]*")|    #   a double-quoted string, or
    (?:''[^'']*'')) #   a single-quoted string.
  *$)               # zero or more times to the end of the line.
'  
   
[regex]::Split($people, $pattern) -replace '^["'']|["'']$', ''

Results in:
me
you
us and them
everyone else
them

In short, this regex matches a string of blanks so long as everything that follows is a non-quote or a quoted string--effectively treating quoted strings as single characters.


A concise solution based on PowerShell's regex-based -split and -match operators (and a verbatim here-string to provide the input):
# Returns the following array:
#   @('me', 'you', 'us and them', 'everyone else', 'them')
@'
me   you   "us and them"   'everyone else' them
'@ -split '"(.*?)"|''(.*?)''|(\S+)' -match '\S'

Note:

Tokens with escaped, embedded " or ' characters (e.g., "Nat ""King"" Cole" are not supported, and any empty tokens ('' or "") are effectively eliminated from the result array.

For an explanation of the regex used with -split as well as the option to experiment with it, see this regex101.com page.

-match '\S' operates on -split's result array and eliminates empty or all-whitespace elements from it, by filtering in only those elements that contain at least one non-whitespace character (\S).

This extra, filtering step is necessary, because -split is being slightly repurposed above: the regex passed to it normally describes the separators between elements, whereas here it describes the elements, and it is the enclosure in (...) (capture groups) that also causes what these groups matched to be included in the result array, in addition to the runs of spaces that are technically now the "elements", as well as an initial, empty element that precedes the first "separator"; -match '\S' in effect eliminates all these unwanted elements.




Alternatively, use .NET APIs directly, namely [regex]::Matches():
$string = @'
me   you   "us and them"   'everyone else' them
'@

# Returns the following array:
#   @('me', 'you', 'us and them', 'everyone else', 'them')
[regex]::Matches($string, '"(?<a>.*?)"|''(?<a>.*?)''|(?<a>\S+)').
  ForEach({ $_.Groups['a'].Value })


This more directly expresses the intent of matching and extracting only the arguments embedded in the string.

Named capture groups ((?<name>...) are used to capture the arguments without enclosing quotes.
Using the same name (?<a>) for multiple groups means that whichever one captures a specific match reports it via that name in the .Groups property of the resulting [Match] instance, and the captured text can therefore be accessed via .Groups['a'].Value


GitHub issue #7867 is a feature request for introducing a -matchall operator, which would enable a more PowerShell-idiomatic solution:
# WISHFUL THINKING, as of PowerShell 7.4.x
($string -matchall '"(?<a>.*?)"|''(?<a>.*?)''|(?<a>\S+)').
  ForEach({ $_.Groups['a'].Value })




Instead of building a regular expression for this, you might also rely on a robust parser (such as the existing PowerShell PSParser):
[System.Management.Automation.PSParser]::Tokenize($people, [ref]$null).Content

Note that parsers usually support more than just quoting rules along with here strings, smart quotes and operators which aren't specifically in - or excluded in your question and example, meaning that these features could be either considered a loss or a bonus to this question.

This is a good suggestion, @iRon, and I'll think about it in future. But the RegEx solution will work across many languages other than PowerShell. Thx.
